# BMW E90 M47TU2 EGR clean

Tags: bmw, egr, e90

I have a BMW E90 2007 with a M47TU2 engine, Can anyone tell me where the EGR valve is?

How to get it off, howto clean it and what cleaning materials are required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BMW use valve overlap to serve EGR. Most if not all of BMW engines DO NOT have an EGR valve. They use a system on the engine that they have named VANOS. This system changes the cam shaft timing so that it allows exhaust gas to remain in the cylinder during the inlet stroke. This has the same effect as an EGR system. [www.bimmerforums.co.uk](http://www.bimmerforums.co.uk) has a very good and detailed explanation.

Comment: this is a Q & A, it serves no use if people tell you to search for something... If someone is googling the question I asked, they'll come here and get a non-helpful answer and go elsewhere..

Comment: Also, your answer doesn't answer any of my specific questions 1) where is it located 2) how do you get it off 3) what is best to clean it with

Comment: BMW, most if not all engines DO NOT have an EGR valve. They use a system on the engine that they have named Vaneos. This system changes the cam shaft timing so that it allows exhaust gas to remain in the cylinder during the inlet stroke. This has the same effect as an EGR system. www.bimmerforums.co.uk has a very good and detailed explanation.

Comment: Thats a better answer :) Can you edit your original and I'll accept it

Comment: Many BMW engines have EGR, petrol and Diesel. Also that link is just a list of unrelated forums.

Answer (score 2):

## Location

It's located between your throttle body and the manifold.
You would remove the air intake and the throttle body from the manifold to best accesss the EGR and clean it.

## Video

Here is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQx_fx8VKY0) cleaning of an EGR (exhaust gas re-circulation) valve that is a similar model to yours.

## Supplies

To clean the valve you will want

- carb/brake cleaner to break down the carbon and unburnt hydro-carbons
- small wire/nylon brush
- oil picks and what not.
- One can of B-12 Carb cleaner

Hope this helpful.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to some other answers claiming that BMW engines do not have an EGR valve, in fact the diesel engines do. Here's a link to the parts catalog showing it, and an illustration on its placement: http://bmwfans.info/parts-catalog/E90/Europe/320d-M47N2/browse/engine/pollutant_reduction_cooling/

Looks like it's on the front of the engine, between the exhaust and the inlet manifold.

Answer (score 0):

As Allan mentioned, this engine does not have an EGR valve.

You might find these parts diagrams helpful: http://www.realoem.com/bmw/partgrp.do?model=VC11&mospid=48821&hg=11

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete EGR best would be to search this [forum](http://www.e90post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=796397), you could find usefull info there. I hope it helps.

Boris

Comment: Another usefull info can be found in this [forum](http://www.e90post.com/forums/showthread.php?t=470936).